# Why is std::bitset::size non-static

Tags: c++, c++11, std, bitset

I can't possibly imagine why it was chose that `std::bitset::size` is non-static. It makes it much harder to get a `constexpr` size; you have to write something like this:

```
template<int val>
struct int_
{
   static const constexpr value = val;
};

template<size_t size>
auto getBitsetSizeIMPL(std::bitset<size>)
{
   return int_<size>{};
}

template<typename BitsetType>
constexpr size_t getBitsetSize()
{
    return decltype(getBitsetSizeIMPL(BitsetType{}))::value;
}
```

When if it were static all you would have to do would be

```
BitsetType::size()
```

and there would be no sacrifice of functionality.

Is there a historical reason that I am missing or is there a technical fact I am missing?

Comment: FWIW, you can do `BitsetType{}.size()`.

Comment: True! Didn't think about that. That is much better. But still,  any reason it can't be static?

Comment: Same reason that `std::array::size` isn't static, I'd imagine. Someone was asking about that last week.

Comment: @lightness To what conclusion?

Comment: @RussellGreene: I do not remember. Hence the implication that if you look for related recent questions, you'll find it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption of a not `constexpr` [`std::bitset::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/size) is incorrect:

```
std::size_t size() const; // until C++11
constexpr std::size_t size();  // since C++11, until C++14
constexpr std::size_t size() const; // since C++14)
```

Comment: But in order to use those,  you have to have a constexpr bitset. It isn't static.

Comment: You aren't answering the question. I know that it is constexpr. I'm just curious why they chose that design choice.

Comment: @RussellGreene: I don't know, but two characters, `{}` or `()` to create an instance, is really not much notational overhead. It's just a little imperfection.

Comment: I totally agree. I'm just curious if there is a reason it isn't static : it will always return the same value for the same type.

Comment: @RussellGreene: You may be on to something. It's the same with `std::array`, except there `std::tuple_size` plays the rôle of free size function. It's not overloaded for `std::bitset`. Curious.