# Why is std::vector::max_size() non-static?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, library-design

Since the maximum size does not depend on particular `std::vector` objects, I guess it should be a static method. But still, the standard prototypes it as non-static, and I cannot figure out why. Logically, one should check the maximum size before creating any `std::vector` objects.

Note that this question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33428441/1348273) one which is basically about `constexpr`.

Comment: "Logically, one should check the maximum size before creating any `std::vector` objects." → Really? `max_size` is optimistic, so verifying that you're under doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: I would says that it might depend of Allocator.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thanks for the mention. That indeed answers my question :-) Always forget the allocator thing.